Moveit setPoseTarget inaccurate
I'm using Moveit! with ros-noetic on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, on a Franka Emika Panda 7DOF robot. When attempting to move the robot using setPoseTarget with a small distance (1 cm), and then calculating the distance between the end and start poses, I find it to be inaccurate, usually 0.03 - 0.04 cm. This doesn't happen when I move the robot to longer distances, such as 20 cm.
I've tried using different planners ("LIN", "PTP", "RTConnect"), I've tried changing the goal tolerance (right now it's set to 0.0015), I also changed the default IK solver to TRAC IK, but nothing seemed to help.
This is my implementation of moving the robot to a pose:
void moveToPose(const geometry_msgs::Pose& pose){
    moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Plan plan;
    move_group_interface.setPlanningTime(3.0);
    move_group_interface.setMaxVelocityScalingFactor(0.1);
    move_group_interface.setMaxAccelerationScalingFactor(0.1);
    move_group_interface.setPoseTarget(pose);
    move_group_interface.setPlannerId("LIN");
    bool success = (move_group_interface.plan(plan) == moveit::core::MoveItErrorCode::SUCCESS);
    if(success){
        ROS_INFO("Planning was successful");
        move_group_interface.execute(plan);
    }
    else{
        ROS_INFO("Planning was not successful");
    } 
}

And this is how I use it:
geometry_msgs::Pose target_pose;
target_pose = robot.getCurrentPose();         
target_pose.position.y += 0.01; // 1 cm
robot.moveToPose(target_pose);

Is this a Moveit problem, or could it be that my robot is not configured properly? Or is my code wrong in any way?
